# How to close tag if current counter is equal?

Tags: php

I have loop inside that I do if:

```
if($i % 3 == 0 || empty($value)){
     echo '</div>';
     $i = 0;
}
```

But there is case when elements in loop not more 3 or 6, them tag is not closed.
How I can check it?

Full code:

```
<? $i = 1; foreach ($medicalSimple as $value):?>
 <?
  if($i == 1){
     echo '<div class="wrapContainer">';
  }
 ?>

// Here HTML code

 <?
   if($i % 3 == 0 || empty($value)){
      echo '</div>';
      $i = 0;
   }
 ?>
<? $i++; endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Can you give a complete example? It's hard to follow with the current partial snippet

Comment: Could you try rephrasing? It's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: It looks correct. When does it give the wrong answer. Can you make an example when it's wrong.

Comment: Do you mean if you finish the loop on 2 you won't have a closing `div`? Also, why set `$i` to 0?

Comment: No i dont get closing tag div. if elements in array two - i get error. Yeah, you are right

Comment: I do like as: `$keyb = $key +1;
        if($i % 3 == 0 || isset($keyb)){
            echo '</div>';
            $i = 1;
        }
        ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($i % 3 == 0 || empty($value)){
      echo '</div>';
      $i = 0;
   }
```

change to this

```
if($i % 3 == 0 || count($medicalSimple )==$i){
      echo '</div>';

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just add another check after the loop, like this:

```
<? if ( $i % 3 == 0 ) { echo '</div>'; } ?>
```

Comment: Probably would want `$i % 3 != 0`. Otherwise echo would have been triggered in loop.

Comment: i tried it with the code above in a sandbox and it worked fine. if you check for not-equal, it will trigger false because of the reset of $i inside the loop every third iteration.